# How do I check a set of data on a set of rules / conditions for categorization?

Tags: c++, pattern-matching

I have a set of bank account entries which I stored in instances of a class `bankAccountEntry` which I defined. The class `bankAccountEntry` has the data members

```
unsigned int year;
unsigned int month;
unsigned int day;
std::string name;
std::string accountNumberConsidered;
std::string  accountNumberContra;
std::string code;
double amount;
std::string sortOfMutation;
std::string note;
```

I want to categorize these bank account entries.

For instance, if the `std::string name` would contain the substring `gasolineStation1` or `gasolineStation2`, it should be categorized under `gasoline`. To realize this categorization, I could for instance check the data members by means of the statements

```
if (std::count(bae.name.begin(), bae.name.end(),"gasolineStation1")>0
    || 
    std::count(bae.name.begin(), bae.name.end(),"gasolineStation2")>0)
{
    bae.setCategory("gasoline");
}
```

For the categorization of all my bank account entries, I have a large set of such predefined rules / conditions, which I want to give as input argument to the main program.

What strategies are there to check each of my bank account entries for the set of rules / conditions until it finds a hit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, big if here, all of the rules are simple name-category mappings this can be done fairly cleanly. If the rules vary... Yuck.

Looking only at the easy case for now,

For ease of reading and explanation define:

```
struct mapping
{
    std::string name;
    std::string category;
}
```

There may be tactical advantages to using `std::pair<std::string,std::string>` instead. And define

```
std::vector<mapping> mappings;
```

Read the name-category pairings from the rules file into `mappings`. Can't give any advice on this because we don't know what the rules look like. Once this is done

```
bool bankAccountEntry::categorize()
{
    for (const mapping & kvp: mappings)
    {
        if (name.find(kvp.name) != std::string::npos)
        {
            setCategory(kvp.category);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is brute force. Depending on how your data looks, for example if it closely follows a naming scheme, you can really speed this up.

If the rules are more complicated, you wind up with something more like:

```
struct mapping
{
    std::function<bool(const bankAccountEntry&)> rule;
    std::string category;
}
```

and

```
std::vector<mapping> mappings;
```

Each `mapping::rule` is a function that takes a `bankAccountEntry` and decides whether or not the `bankAccountEntry` fits the rule. For example:

```
bool gasolineStationRule(const bankAccountEntry& bae)
{
    return std::count(bae.name.begin(), bae.name.end(),"gasolineStation1")>0 ||       
           std::count(bae.name.begin(), bae.name.end(),"gasolineStation2")>0;
}
```

Which won't work [because `std::count` doesn't work like that](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count).

Something like

```
bool gasolineStationRule(const bankAccountEntry& bae)
{
    return (bae.name.find("gasolineStation1")!= std::string::npos) ||
           (bae.name.find("gasolineStation2")!= std::string::npos);
}
```

will, but can be improved on by searching once for "gasolineStation" and then, if "gasolineStation" is found, testing the character after it for '1' or '2'.

How you get the `rule`s into the vector is going to be quite fun. It could require a large pool of specialized functions, an army of Lambdas, or a partridge in a pair tree. Not enough specified in the question to say for sure.

It will probably look something like

```
mappings.push_back(mapping{&gasolineStationRule, "gasoline"})
```

or by adding a constructor to `mapping`

```
mapping(std::function<bool(const bankAccountEntry&)> newrule,
        std::string newcategory): rule(newrule), category(newcategory)
{

}
```

you may get a small performance improvement from

```
mappings.emplace_back(&gasolineStationRule, "gasoline")
```

Anyway...

```
bool bankAccountEntry::categorize()
{
    for (const mapping & kvp: mappings)
    {
        if (kvp.rule(*this))
        {
            setCategory(kvp.category);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And again the more you know about the rules and how predicable they are the more  you can optimize.

[Also look at `std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) as a possible replacement for the guts of `bankAccountEntry::categorize`.

[Documentation on `std::function`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

Comment: Could you please give me an example of a definition of a `std::function`? Could you perhaps define a `std::function` for the rule I mentioned? So `if (std::count(bae.name.begin(), bae.name.end(),"gasolineStation1")>0
    || 
    std::count(bae.name.begin(), bae.name.end(),"gasolineStation2")>0)`.

Comment: `std::function` is a wrapper around an everyday ordinary function to make it easier to pass around. It also accepts functions with parameters bound with [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) or [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). Either will help you specialize a more generic function, for example, you can replace the hard-coded "gasolineStation1" with a bound string allowing you to use the function demonstrated in the edit with different strings. That's getting way off topic, though. you're better off asking a new question.